# Regex - Combine regular expressions - Beginning and end of string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have two examples of what I need with two differents scenarios:

**1. The first one:**

If I have this simple string:

```
var message = "Hello World";
```

and I want this result with regular expressions:

```
'Hello World'
```

I know I can do:

```
message.replace(/^/, "'").replace(/$/, "'");
```

***My question:* How I can do it to make it with one *regex*. I mean, something like this: (of course, this doesn't work):**

`message.replace(/(^|$)/, "'");`

**2. The second one:**

Again the simple string:

```
var message = "Hello World";
```

and I want this result with regular expressions:

```
#Hola Mundo%
```

And of course, I can do:

```
message.replace(/^/, "#").replace(/$/, "%");
```

And the same question: **How I can do it to make it with one *regex*?**

I know that this is a simple question, but it could be glad to have the answer.

Comment: `message.replace(/(^|$)/g, "'");` with `g` modifier

Comment: What you do hardly requires a regex. Just concatenate the strings. `message = "'" + message + "'"` and `message = "#" + message + "%"`.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, thanks. This answer my first example. And the second one?

Comment: @robe007: The second one is `.replace(/^[^]*$/, "#$&%")`, but why regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My friend, yes I know. But I just want to know how to do it with Regex. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most appropriate way to do what you need is using string concatenation.

If you want to learn regex:

1. `message.replace(/^|$/g, "'");` - you need to use `/g` to perform a global search and replace

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `|`  - or
- `$` - end of string
- `/g`  - perform global search and replace

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX1eS4/1)

2. `message.replace(/^[^]*$/, "#$&%")` or `message.replace(/^[\s\S]*$/, "#$&%")`

**Explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^]*` - zero or more any characters (in JS, `[^]` means *not nothing*) (this can be replaced with `[\s\S]*` / `[\w\W]*` / `[\d\D]*` to match any characters from the BMP plane)
- `$`  - end of string.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xX1eS4/3)

The `$&` in the replacement pattern is the backreference to the whole match. `$1` references Group 1, i.e. the first `(...)` capturing group value if it is defined in the pattern, but if you need to refer to the whole match, you should use `$&` construct.

Comment: Can you please, improve your answer and explain me separately the two ways of the second answer?. I understand the first.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanation. Only one more thing: What means `$&` inside the replace?

Comment: Ah, that is the backreference to the whole match. `$1` references Group 1, i.e. the first `(...)` capturing group value, but if you need to refer to the whole match, you can't use (it is not supported in all browsers) `$0`.

Comment: Dziękuję bardzo ! Greetings to Poland ! Very nice explanation !